# "unable to verify the first certificate" when deploy the Nextjs with Nginx

Tags: nginx, next.js, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Background:** I'm trying to deploy a Nextjs 14 (APP router) project with Nginx for my team. We want to support both http(will be redirected to https) and https. To make the connection run on http, I set up a Nginx instance (on the same machine with my nextjs app) to redirect all http to https, and pass all https connection to the localhost:3000 where my Nextjs app runs.

**Problem:** I can access the web page, but all the client component which use internal api seems broken. The error from browser:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://nextapp.aaa.com/api/images/internal/preview”
```

The error from the server side:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)
      at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
  }
}
```

Here's my Nginx config (New to Nginx and front end dev. Got from other blog):

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name  nextapp.aaa.com;

        ssl_certificate         F:/Server/certificate/nextapp.aaa.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     F:/Server/certificate/unsecure.key;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;
        ssl_ciphers     ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        }
    }

    server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  nextapp.aaa.com;
       return      301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

After digging a lot, I guess the problem is due to the http api call. But I can't understand why, seems that https connections are proxy to localhost:3000 successfully except for api. Then I tried to change my api call to https. The result is that even my server components can't work. The error on the server side is the same as before.

**Expect result:** Users can access the web app via both http and https. If they type http://nextapp.aaa.com, it will be redirected to https version.